# Problemas com o select de html

Tags: javascript, html

Tenhos os seguintes códigos em html e javascript:

```js
/**
 * Created by Erick on 22/11/2014.
 */

var data = new Date();
var meses = new Array("Janeiro", "Fevereiro", "Março", "Abril", "Maio", "Junho", "Julho", "Agosto", "Setembro", "Outubro", "Novembro", "Dezembro");
var dias = new Array("Domingo", "Segunda-feira", "Terça-feira", "Quarta-feira", "Quinta-feira", "Sexta-feira", "Sabado");

var dia = data.getDay();
var dian = data.getDate();
var mes = data.getMonth()
var ano = data.getFullYear()

function proxSemana() {
    while(dia != 1){
        proxDia();
    }
}

function proxDia(){
    dia++;
    if(dia > 6){
        dia = 0;
    }
    dian++;
    if(meses[mes] == "Janeiro" || meses[mes] == "Março" || meses[mes] == "Maio" || meses[mes] == "Julho" || meses[mes] == "Agosto" || meses[mes] == "Outubro" || meses[mes] == "Dezembro"){
        if(dian > 31){
            dian = 1;
            mes++;
            if(mes > 11){
                mes = 0;
                ano++;
            }
        }
    }else if(meses[mes] == "Abril" || meses[mes] == "Junho" || meses[mes] == "Setembro" || meses[mes] == "Novembro"){
        if(dian > 30){
            dian = 1;
            mes++;
        }

    }else{
        if(dian > 28){
            dian = 1;
            mes++;
        }
    }

}


proxDia();
proxSemana();
document.write(dias[dia]  + ", " + dian + " de " + meses[mes] + " de " + ano + "<br>");
proxDia()
proxSemana()
document.write(dias[dia]  + ", " + dian + " de " + meses[mes] + " de " + ano + "<br>");
proxDia()
proxSemana()
document.write(dias[dia]  + ", " + dian + " de " + meses[mes] + " de " + ano + "<br>");
proxDia()
proxSemana()
document.write(dias[dia]  + ", " + dian + " de " + meses[mes] + " de " + ano + "<br>");
proxDia()
proxSemana()
document.write(dias[dia]  + ", " + dian + " de " + meses[mes] + " de " + ano + "<br>");
proxDia()
proxSemana()
document.write(dias[dia]  + ", " + dian + " de " + meses[mes] + " de " + ano + "<br>");
proxDia()
proxSemana()
document.write(dias[dia]  + ", " + dian + " de " + meses[mes] + " de " + ano + "<br>");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>SI1</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script_pagina3.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>

    <select>
        <option value="1° Semana"></option>
        <option value="2° Semana"></option>
        <option value="3° Semana"></option>
        <option value="4° Semana"></option>
        <option value="5° Semana"></option>
        <option value="6° Semana"></option>
    </select>

    </body>

</html>
```

E gostaria de fazer um formulário com um select cujo as opções fossem os 6 document.write do código javascript, mas não consegui.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sugiro outra abordagem, mais fácil de manter.

```js
var data = new Date();
var segunda = segundaMaisProxima(data);
var meses = new Array("Janeiro", "Fevereiro", "Março", "Abril", "Maio", "Junho", "Julho", "Agosto", "Setembro", "Outubro", "Novembro", "Dezembro");
var dias = new Array("Domingo", "Segunda-feira", "Terça-feira", "Quarta-feira", "Quinta-feira", "Sexta-feira", "Sabado");

function segundaMaisProxima(d) {
    var diaSemana = d.getDay();
    var diff = d.getDate() + (1 - diaSemana);
    return new Date(d.setDate(diff));
}

function gerarTexto(d) {
    return dias[d.getDay()] + ", " + d.getDate() + " de " + meses[d.getMonth()] + " de " + d.getFullYear();
}

$('select option').each(function (i) {
    segunda.setDate(segunda.getDate() + (i ? 7 : 0));
    this.innerHTML = gerarTexto(segunda);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
    <option value="1° Semana"></option>
    <option value="2° Semana"></option>
    <option value="3° Semana"></option>
    <option value="4° Semana"></option>
    <option value="5° Semana"></option>
    <option value="6° Semana"></option>
</select>
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yekh9ucs/

Assim ele calcula a primeira segunda feira e gera as próximas adicionando 7 dias a cada iteração do loop que corre todas as `option` que o select tem.

Comment: Realmente, ficou bem melhor, obrigado!

Comment: Mas caso eu queira acrescentar esse código javascript como o título de uma div, da mesma maneira que no select, é possível? Só que ao invés de aparecer só a próxima segunda "Segunda-feira, 24 de Novembro de 2014", aparecer a próxima semana "Segunda-feira, 24 de Novembro de 2014 - Domingo, 30 de Novembro de 2014", eu tava implementando isso usando as funções proxDia e proxSemana que criei, mas do seu jeito parece ser bem mais prático.

Answer (score 1):

Sugiro que você depois tente colocar essa sequência de comandos em uma estrutura de repetição.

Quanto ao uso do select, você pode fazer isso usando [a interface para o DOM provida no JavaScript](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_select_add.asp).

```js
/**
 * Created by Erick on 22/11/2014.
 */

var data = new Date();
var meses = new Array("Janeiro", "Fevereiro", "Março", "Abril", "Maio", "Junho", "Julho", "Agosto", "Setembro", "Outubro", "Novembro", "Dezembro");
var dias = new Array("Domingo", "Segunda-feira", "Terça-feira", "Quarta-feira", "Quinta-feira", "Sexta-feira", "Sabado");

var dia = data.getDay();
var dian = data.getDate();
var mes = data.getMonth()
var ano = data.getFullYear()

function proxSemana() {
    while(dia != 1){
        proxDia();
    }
}

function proxDia(){
    dia++;
    if(dia > 6){
        dia = 0;
    }
    dian++;
    if(meses[mes] == "Janeiro" || meses[mes] == "Março" || meses[mes] == "Maio" || meses[mes] == "Julho" || meses[mes] == "Agosto" || meses[mes] == "Outubro" || meses[mes] == "Dezembro"){
        if(dian > 31){
            dian = 1;
            mes++;
            if(mes > 11){
                mes = 0;
                ano++;
            }
        }
    }else if(meses[mes] == "Abril" || meses[mes] == "Junho" || meses[mes] == "Setembro" || meses[mes] == "Novembro"){
        if(dian > 30){
            dian = 1;
            mes++;
        }

    }else{
        if(dian > 28){
            dian = 1;
            mes++;
        }
    }

}

var select = document.getElementById("select");

proxDia();
proxSemana();
select.add(new Option(dias[dia]  + ", " + dian + " de " + meses[mes] + " de " + ano));
proxDia()
proxSemana()
select.add(new Option(dias[dia]  + ", " + dian + " de " + meses[mes] + " de " + ano));
proxDia()
proxSemana()
select.add(new Option(dias[dia]  + ", " + dian + " de " + meses[mes] + " de " + ano));
proxDia()
proxSemana()
select.add(new Option(dias[dia]  + ", " + dian + " de " + meses[mes] + " de " + ano));
proxDia()
proxSemana()
select.add(new Option(dias[dia]  + ", " + dian + " de " + meses[mes] + " de " + ano));
proxDia()
proxSemana()
select.add(new Option(dias[dia]  + ", " + dian + " de " + meses[mes] + " de " + ano));
proxDia()
proxSemana()
select.add(new Option(dias[dia]  + ", " + dian + " de " + meses[mes] + " de " + ano));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>SI1</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script_pagina3.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>

    <select id="select">
    </select>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Valeu cara, ajudou bastante!